# How to access a local object inside a class method in a module?

Tags: python

I was trying to access a local variable inside of a class that is in a module.
So Far I can only access it while doing the call inside the module itself and not as a import.

this is my only successfull attempt to retrieve "coisa". is there a easyer way to call it?

```
class Hello():
    def MyObject():
        coisa = 22
        return coisa

link = Hello.MyObject()
print(link)
```

But this is the situation I am trying to actually overcome. Importing a module and access a object inside it class and function.
Main.py

```
import Module

link = Module.Hello.MyObject()
print(link)
```

Module.py

```
coisa = "67"
class Hello():
    def MyObject():
        coisa = "22"
        return coisa
```

Comment: Don't really understand what you expect. Do you want to access the ```coisa``` variable outside of your module, without importing a class/function ?

Comment: Don't really understand what you expect. In your first code snippet, ``coisa`` is a local variable inside a function. It is created dynamically. What do you mean by accessing it?

Comment: Well I want to access "coisa" as I previously stated before. On one case I try on a single file and on the other I try the same situation with the use of modules.

Comment: But I don't know it feels so weird. I feel like I am doing it all wrong. the fact I need to execute the function to actually get the value inside. I guess it is me not being used to Python yet I guess then :\

Comment: in my head I should be just be able to write "Module.Hello.MyObject.coisa" and get it

Comment: I'm afraid I can hardly make sense of your question. Of course you cannot directly access a local variable (a variable defined in a function), that's the very definition of a local variable - it only exists during the function's execution and can only be accessed from within the function - except of course if the function returns it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot acces `coisa` var directly if it is defined in your function as it is a local variable.

In an hypothetic case where `coisa` would be defined outside your function, you could access it directly. For example :

Module.py

```py
COISA = "67"

class Hello():
    def MyObject():
        coisa = "22"
        return coisa
```

You can access COISA from your external code by calling it directly. Note the Uppercase naming style, conforming to PEP-8 naming convention for constants.

```py
import Module

link = Module.COISA 
print(link) # Will print 67
```

Or you can access coisa, defined locally in your function, in Lowercase naming style, this way. You have to return the variable value in your function as it is a local variable for your function.

```py
import Module

link = Module.Hello.MyObject()
print(link) # Will print 22
```

**EDIT**

Note that you can also directly access to a variable defined in your class.
For example :

Module.py

```py
COISA = "67"

class Hello():

    coisa_in_my_class = "85"

    def MyObject():
        coisa = "22"
        return coisa
```

You can call `coisa_in_my_class` easily :

```py
import Module

link = Module.Hello.coisa_in_my_class
print(link) # Will print 85
```

Comment: " Note the Uppercase naming style, conforming to PEP-8 naming convention for global variables." => actually, this is the convention for pseudo-constants, not for globals (I say "pseudo-constants" because Python has no support for user-defined symbolic constants).

Comment: You are totally right. Thanks for specifying this, will correct my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand the question but I think you mean a `staticmethod` so try this

```
class Hello():
    @staticmethod
    def MyObject():
        coisa = "22"
        return coisa
```

Then you can

```
import Module

link = Module.Hello.MyObject()
print(link)  # 22
```